# $locationChangeStart event triggers too late

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the next problem.

I have different behaviours of `<a>` elements. I have a controller which handle 2 events:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    console.log("$destroy");
});

$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function () {
    console.log("$locationChangeStart");
});
```

Sometimes **$locationChangeStart** event fired first, but sometimes **$destroy** event fired first.

I need to prevent changing page, so I need **$locationChangeStart** to be fired first.

Please, someone has any thoughts, why different `<a>` have different sequence of events?

**UPD**
I use the same `<a>` element in different parts of page

```
<a href="#/overview">test</a>
```

Comment: did you ever get this resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent changing page it doesn't matter which one is launch first.

In your **$locationChangeStart** add the **event** object:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // will prevent the location change
});
```